# html - how to set fixed column width for a specific row of cell, regardless of other rows?

Tags: html

I have one table.

I would like to set different cell width for different rows.

For example, at the third row, I would like to set the EQUAL column width of 3rd and 4th column. No matter the 3rd column has text overflow.

original output:

[image]

expected output:

[image]

Is it possible to do so? Thanks you very much!

```
<style type="text/css"> .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#aabcfe;margin:0px auto;} .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aabcfe;color:#669;background-color:#e8edff;} .tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aabcfe;color:#039;background-color:#b9c9fe;} .tg .tg-s6z2{text-align:center} .tg .tg-vn4c{background-color:#D2E4FC} .tg .tg-0ord{text-align:right} .table {table-layout: fixed;} </style>


<table class="tg" table width="500">   <tr>
    <th class="tg-s6z2" colspan="6">Results</th>   </tr>   <tr>
    <td class="tg-vn4c" width="5%">No</td>
    <td class="tg-vn4c" width="15%">Competition</td>
    <td class="tg-vn4c" width="20%">John</td>
    <td class="tg-vn4c" width="20%">Adam</td>
    <td class="tg-vn4c" width="20%">Robert</td>
    <td class="tg-vn4c" width="20%">Paul</td>   </tr>   <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">1</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Swimming</td>
    <td class="tg-0ord" colspan="2">line1<br>line 2<br>line 3<br>12345678901234567890123451234567890<br><br></td>
    <td class="tg-0ord" colspan="2">ABCD<br><br></td>   </tr> </table>
```

Comment: I do not believe that is possible. It breaks the whole idea of a table.

Comment: Technically it is possible using `colspan`s. But it would not be very flexible and would make little sense semantically. I would consider changing your table layout.

Comment: I dissuade you from using tables at all, but it's certainly possibly using nested tables.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question:

*Technically*, yes it is possible with tables using empty cells, colspans and manipulating borders. In fact, I made it.

#### *Don't* do this

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
.noborder {
  border: none;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}
.leftborder {
  border-left: solid 1px #000
}
.rightborder {
  border-right: solid 1px #000
}
```

```html
<h1>Don't do this!</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Comp</th>
    <td>John</td>
    <td class="noborder">Matthew</td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Luke</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Swimming</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="noborder">Details</td>
    <td colspan="3" class="noborder leftborder rightborder">Details</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Practically though, this is overly complex and **impossible to maintain**; it also defeats the purpose of a table.

---

### Possible alternative

This is a possible idea, though it could still be difficult to maintain and I don't know exactly what you are trying to display.

#### Sticking with a table

Depending on what information you are trying to display, you could use a table for this with a different layout. The rowspans join the information relevant to each name.

[image: Screenshot]

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">No</th>
      <th scope="col">Competition</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Details 1</th>
      <th scope="col">Details 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" rowspan="5">1</th>
      <th scope="row" rowspan="5">Swimming</th>
      <td>John</td>
      <td rowspan="3">This info is relevant to John, Steven and Mark</td>
      <td rowspan="2">This info is relevant to John and Steven</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Steven</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td rowspan="2">This info is relevant to Mark and Peter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Peter</td>
      <td>The info is only relevant to Peter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use style sheet that sounds like hacks to this.. because doing this in table property isn't possible

[see this `jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/oav5ccow/)